Export euler plot to powerpoint
I have an euler plot created with eulerr package.
Sample data:
fit <- euler(c(
   "A" = 10000,
   "B" = 7000,
   "A&B" = 600))

plot(fit,
     quantities = list(fontsize = 9),
     fills = c("#8ABDAF", "#DC8E8D"),
     fontsize = 9,
     main  = list(label = "Title"),
     labels = NULL,
     legend = list(labels = c("A", "B"))
     )


I want to export this base R plot to powerpoint not as an image but in a way where I can modify each element.
As it's not a ggplot, I can't export using export package. But it does seem like there is a possibility with a combination of the officer and rvg packages.
I've seen another thread using the function ph_with_vg from the rvg package, but after installing rvg that function is not existing.
I tried the following:
read_pptx() %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with(dml(code = {
    plot(fit)
  }), 
  location = ph_location_type(type = "body")) %>% 
  print(target = "Euler_fit.pptx")

But I get the error:
Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  StartTag: invalid element name [68]

I have no idea what that means.
Does anybody know how to do this?
Thanks.

Note that this is a grid plot and not a base plot.
You are just missing a plot statement:
library(eulerr)
library(rvg)
library(officer)

fit <- euler(c(
  "A" = 10000,
  "B" = 7000,
  "A&B" = 600))

p <- plot(fit,
     quantities = list(fontsize = 9),
     fills = c("#8ABDAF", "#DC8E8D"),
     fontsize = 9,
     main  = list(label = "Title"),
     labels = NULL,
     legend = list(labels = c("A", "B"))
)


read_pptx() |> 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") |> 
  ph_with(dml(code = {
    plot(p)
  }), 
  location = ph_location_type(type = "body")) |> 
  print(target = "Euler_fit.pptx")


Save as SVG, then insert.
library(eulerr)
library(officer)
library(magrittr) # pipe

fit <- euler(c(
  "A" = 10000,
  "B" = 7000,
  "A&B" = 600))

# output as svg file:
img.file <- "tmp.svg"

svg(filename = img.file)

plot(fit,
     quantities = list(fontsize = 9),
     fills = c("#8ABDAF", "#DC8E8D"),
     fontsize = 9,
     main  = list(label = "Title"),
     labels = NULL,
     legend = list(labels = c("A", "B"))
)

dev.off()

read_pptx() %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  ph_with(external_img(img.file),
          location = ph_location_type(type = "body"), 
          use_loc_size = TRUE) %>% 
  print(target = "Euler_fit.pptx")


Have you tried {export}?
fit = eulerr::euler(c("A" = 10000, "B" = 7000, "A&B" = 600))
plot(fit, quantities = list(fontsize = 9), fills = c("#8ABDAF", "#DC8E8D"),
     fontsize = 9L, main  = list(label = "Title"), labels = NULL,
     legend = list(labels = c("A", "B")))
export::graph2ppt(file="plot.pptx", width=6L, height=5L, append=TRUE)  


Thanks this worked, I don't know why it didn't work when I tried.
